# MySQL CASE , SUM, GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, case

I want sum of payment status from two differnt columns based on paymentstatus value - but this query returns null for sum. Why is it not working?

```
select payment_status,
CASE 
WHEN 'PAID' THEN sum(paid_amount)
when 'Not Paid' then sum(total_amount_due )
END 
from monthly_fee
group by payment_status;
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: In the absence of a data set, I'm baffled as to how my fellow correspondents have arrived at any semblance of an answer

Comment: @Strawberry I was in the process of writing something similar when I realised that the SQL was clearly wrong and easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(CASE WHEN payment_status = 'PAID' THEN paid_amount else 0 end) as paid,
       sum(CASE WHEN payment_status = 'Not Paid' THEN total_amount_due else 0 end) as due
from monthly_fee
```

Comment: Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. This would add searchable content (well you must know that -just doing reviews)

Answer (score 0):

If you want this conditionally, you need to include the column in the `case`:

```
select payment_status,
       (case payment_status
             when 'Paid' then sum(paid_amount)
             when 'Not Paid' then sum(total_amount_due )
        end) 
from monthly_fee
group by payment_status;
```

This seems like a strange way to write the query, unless you really want two rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHEN` clauses aren't a condition.

I'd expect to see something like

```
select payment_status,
CASE 
WHEN payment_status = 'PAID' THEN sum(paid_amount)
when payment_status = 'Not Paid' then sum(total_amount_due )
END 
from monthly_fee
group by payment_status;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query:

```
select sum(if(payment_status = 'PAID', paid_amount, 0) 
       + if(payment_status = 'Not Paid', total_amount_due, 0)) 
from monthly_fee
group by payment_status;
```